# Expanding dynamically relative positioned container with absolute positioned content inside using jquery

Tags: jquery, resize, expand

I'm trying to expand dinamically with Jquery the relatively positioned container div, since the UL's inside are absolutely positioned and FadedIn and FadedOut. The whole thing needs to be dynamic since every UL has a different height as it contains a varying number of LIs.

**Here's my HTML code**

```
<div id="container">
<nav id="type-navigation">
<ul id="nav_categories" class="subs">
    <li><a href="#">Category 1</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Category 2</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**And here's my jQuery**

```
$("#type-navigation #nav_categories > li > a").click(function(event){           
      event.preventDefault();
});

$(".subs > li > a").click(function() {
$(this).parents('.subs').find('ul').hide();
if($(this).next("ul").is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next("ul").fadeOut("slow");
} else {
    $(this).next("ul").fadeIn("slow");
}
return false;
});
```

This is the CSS for the above elements

```
#container {
overflow: hidden;
padding: 20px 0 !important;
background: none;}
#type-navigation ul ul{
position: absolute;
top:0;
right: 20px;
}

#type-navigation > ul > li > ul {
 display:none;   
}​
```

Comment: can you show the css code for these elements only?

Comment: If you want to resize the height of #container append this code $('#container').height($(this).next("ul").height()); after $(this).next("ul").fadeOut("slow"); and $(this).next("ul").fadeIn("slow");

Comment: Almost… the fact is that the previously hidden LIs inside the children UL don't get displayed somehow! It all looks cropped.